# Flexbox: Make a 2x2 grid when 4 in a row doesn't fit

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an `<ul>` with four `<li>` inside, each of these have 20% width, but a min-width of 200px. Now, whenever I resize the viewport so 4 in a row doesn't fit, instead of drawing the `<li>` in a 2x2 grid, it puts 3 in a row, and the one remaining on another line.

[As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIxMF.jpg)

What flexbox property I have to use to make a 2x2 grid whenever 4 items in a row doesn't fit?

Comment: provide your code so that we can analyze

Comment: Try to wrap the inner of your `li` in an additional element, so you can set the `li` itself to 50% (to get two per row) and the wrapper to your desired max-width.

Comment: If you want 4 `li` in a row use `flex-flow: row wrap;`.

Comment: Media queries...look it up.

Comment: oh...and *"flexbox is not a grid system"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media query to adjust the `flex-basis` of your `<li>`s when the viewport can not contain all 4 items on a single row anymore.

See this [example](https://codepen.io/JesmoDrazik/pen/WErvdJ?editors=0100) on codepen.

Comment: I thought that Flexbox might have a property to do this by itself, but I guess using media querys is the best option. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a pro of css grid layout, but maybe it allows you to do it without media queries.